# How to get value from an array, only those what is greater than all elements to its right

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to write a function to get all numbers, what is greater than all elements to its right.

**Example** if i have an array like this:

```
arr = [ 75,47,42,56,13,55];
```

*I want a result like this* `[75,56,55]`in a new array.

**Other example** if i have an array like this:

```
arr = [16,17,14,3,14,5,2]
```

*I want a result like:* `[17,14,5,2]`

What methods can i use to get this result whatever numbers i have in an array?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: array.sort should help you => https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort

Comment: Shouldn't your expected array be `[75,47,56,55]` because `47` > `42`

Comment: It has to be greater than **all** elements to its right

Comment: This is a typical task for `.reduceRight()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` the array. `splice` the array to get all the numbers on the right. Use `every` to check if all array elements are greater than the value.

```js
let arr = [75, 47, 42, 56, 13, 55];
let result = arr.filter((v, i, a) => [...a].splice(i + 1, a.length).every(o => v > o));

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate from the right side and check against the latest found greatest value.

```js
function greaterThanRight(array) {
    return array.reduceRight((r, v) => [].concat(v <= r[0] ? [] : v, r), [])
}

console.log([[75, 47, 42, 56, 13, 55], [16, 17, 14, 3, 14, 5, 2]].map(greaterThanRight).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for` loop where inner loop has index starting with the index value of the match having highest right value:

```js
var arr = [ 75,47,42,56,13,55];
var res = [];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  var highestValue = arr[i];
  for(var j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
    if(highestValue < arr[j]){
      highestValue = arr[j];
      i = j;
      break;
    }
  }
  res.push(highestValue);
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [75,47,42,56,13,55];
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    // a = current item in array
    // b = next item in array
    return b - a;
});
var newArr = arr.slice(0,3);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: How can you say that you need to slice exactly 3 elements from the array?

Comment: Ops, i saw RedruM post, it confused me, sorry.

Comment: Do you need to get the highest number in an array?

Comment: Bruno - Because your question is a comment to your answer, you need to get the attention of the person who posted the question. Start your comment with - @ in from of his name - like `@RedruM Do you need...?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just start checking from the right.keep a variable max and update it whenever you found a new max

```js
var arr = [ 75,47,42,56,13,55];

function findMaxRight(arr){
var res=[]
var max = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER

for(var i=arr.length -1; i>=0;i--){
   if(arr[i]> max){
     res.unshift(arr[i])
        max = arr[i]
   }
}
return res
}

console.log(findMaxRight(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be to loop your array, get the current item and get the rest of the array after the current item using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Then sort the rest of the array descending and get the first entry which is the highest one.

If the current value is larger than the highest one, it is larger then all the values on the right:

```js
let items = [75, 47, 42, 56, 13, 55];
let result = [];

items.forEach((item, index) => {
  let head = items[index];
  let tail = items.slice(index + 1).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });
  if ((head > tail[0]) || (index === items.length - 1)) {
    result.push(head);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to do this : find the `max` and if it's the current number store it, continue with the new array `looping = looping.slice(1)`

```
let arr = [75,47,42,56,13,55];
let looping = [...arr];
let finish = arr.reduce( (acc, x) => {
  if(x === Math.max(...looping)) acc.push(x);
  looping = looping.slice(1);
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(finish) // [75,56,55]
```